# Error preallocating sequence numbers. The sequence table information is not complete

Tags: oracle11g, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

EclipseLink 2.6.3, JPA 2.0, IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8 and JTA enabled

I'm currently facing this weird error suddenly and happening intermittently

> Exception [EclipseLink-4011] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception
>   Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  The sequence table
>   information is not complete.

My sequence generators in entities are like below

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="AlrtSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="AlrtSeq",sequenceName="ALR_SEQ1",allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="ALERT_NO")
    private Integer Number;
```

I have debugged Eclipselink source code and it throws error at this method

**StandardSequence.java**

```
public Vector getGeneratedVector(Accessor accessor, AbstractSession writeSession, String seqName, int size) {
    if (shouldUsePreallocation()) {
        Number value = updateAndSelectSequence(accessor, writeSession, seqName, size);
        if (value == null) {
            throw DatabaseException.errorPreallocatingSequenceNumbers();
        }
        return createVector(value, seqName, size);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can be select seq.nextVal from dual can be null ? Because that's what internally happens in **updateAndSelectSequence()** method.

I have also enabled **((AbstractSession)session).setIsConcurrent(true);** for improving performance, in my SessionCustomizer class.Does this property has to do something with this ?

**Exception stack trace**

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4011] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error preallocating sequence numbers.  The sequence table information is not complete.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.errorPreallocatingSequenceNumbers(DatabaseException.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.getGeneratedVector(StandardSequence.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.Sequence.getGeneratedVector(Sequence.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager$Preallocation_NoTransaction_State.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.assignSequenceNumber(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4288)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4187)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(CollectionMapping.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:951)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
```

Comment: How have you configured EclipseLink so it knows it is using an Oracle database?  Try specifying the target database is Oracle11 if that is what you are using: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm

Comment: @chris yes I have already configured it, and my app was working fine and suddenly this issue started occurring

Comment: So what changed? Show your configuration, and the exception stack.  As to  setIsConcurrent, why did you start using it, and why would you suggest it is involved? it is a very specific optimization, so hopefully you had a specific need for it.

Comment: Yes I have read from James Sutherland blog that setIsConcurrent to true will enable Eclipselink to execute queries in multiple threads to improve performance to fetch data in fast manner. This issue started to occur after I added this property hence I'm suspecting it.Updating question with entire stack trace

Comment: I would not use it unless you specifically need that functionality. Executing queries in multiple threads is not the default for a reason, and there are many other performance options that might help more. If this started occurring non-deterministically after you added this setting, file a bug on it as it likely isn't mixing with the query used for native sequence objects, returning null instead of the value.  Table sequencing or preallocation of additional values might alleviate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensures the existence of sequences values in the database .
- Rewrite the name(the same or new name) of persistence-unit then clean and build project.